# Git asking for personal access token

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started using WSL with Neovim to code and I tried to push my commits on my GitHub repo but it asked for my personal access token and username whereas gitbash is directly pushing my commits. is there any way I can resolve this in terminal too?

What my Terminal is displaying

[image: What my Terminal is displaying]

What git bash is displaying

[image: What git bash is displaying]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git

It basically told me to run this command and it's working now: git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"